# Is there a shorter way to match the regex /a|b|ab/

Tags: regex

I am making a compiler and need to match 1 or 2 of two different patterns e.g. `+`,`=`,`+=` or `else`,`if`,`else if`

so far I can do:

```
/\b(else( if)?|(else )?if)\b/
```

The regex above works but the patterns `if` and `else` and mentioned twice.

is there a better way that doesn't require making a copy of each of the words?

Comment: don't use regex to parse nested expressions (programming languages, html, json, ...) they aren't suited for that. Use or write a proper parser instead

Comment: See `\b(?:else(?:\s+(if))?|(?1))\b|[+]=?|=` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMBNj4/1), does it solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The general way to factor all you say above is this

```
(?:\+=?|=|else(?:[ ]if)?|if)
```

No other boundary conditions are asserted around this.
And nothing other than a single space is assumed between the `else if`.

```
 (?:
    \+ =?
  | =
  | else
    (?: [ ] if )?
  | if
 )
```